# Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in Codeigniter 2 and PHP 5.1

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, dompdf

I use PHP 5.6 in my localhost and this script for generating pdf is working well. But in the server which is using PHP 5.1 I got that error. Here is the script in application/libraries/pdf.php.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once (dirname(__FILE__)) . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

class Pdfgenerator {

   function __construct() {
      $this->ci =& get_instance();

      $this->dompdf = new DOMPDF();

   }

   function generate($data){
      $html = $this->ci->load->view($data['template'],$data,true);
      $paper_size = isset($data['paper_size']) ? $data['paper_size'] : 'A4';
      $orientation = isset($data['orientation']) ? $data['orientation'] : 'potrait';
      $this->dompdf->set_paper($paper_size,$orientation);
      $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
      $this->dompdf->render();
      $this->dompdf->stream($data['filename'].'.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));                
   }
}
```

What should I change to make it works in PHP 5.1?

Comment: [PHP 5.1 is dead for more than 12 years now](http://php.net/eol.php). And it was not a very good version anyway. PHP 5 introduced a lot of major changes in the language and in the interpreter and the versions 5.0, 5.1 and 5.2 had a lot of bugs. They had short life as they were replaced by subsequent, better versions. Anyway, as of 2019, PHP is officially not maintained any more and even PHP 7.0, that was released 3 years ago (December 2015), has been retired at the end of 2018. Your best move is to install PHP 7.2 or, if this is not possible, PHP 5.4 or a newer 5.x version.

Comment: @axiac that's probably right, but the issue is that the DOM extension is not installed. @Abaij if you have root access to your server and assuming apt is the package manager, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install php-xml`. Obviously, it's better to upgrade PHP to a newer version.

Comment: You need to install the xml-extension (which includes the DOMDocument). But as @axiac pointed out, you should _really_ upgrade your server. Trying to sort this out on PHP 5.1 is a bad idea. Your server will be exposed because of old, insecure software. You would also notice a major performance difference if you upgraded to php 7.2+

Comment: thanks guys for your comments. yeah I do understand that the php version absolutely need to be upgraded but unfortunately that's not my decision to make